# Differentiablity and Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a connection between these two concepts for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Does one imply the other under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the implications is true in general, in fact $f(x)=x^2$ is differentiable but not uniformly continuous, while $$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
&|x|-1 & -1< x<1 \\
& 0  & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right. 
$$
is uniformly continuous but not differentiable.

To answer your second question.. I can't see any reasonable situation when uniform continuity implies differentiability. What is true is that every function which is differentiable and has bounded derivative is uniformly continuous.
I hope it helps ;)

Comment: A function may also be uniformly continuous and not differentiable anywhere where it is defined. Just take any non-differentiable continuous function on a closed interval (of which there are plenty (e.g., Weierstrass functions)) and remember that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.